# Is there an efficienct way to get field offset in pyshark

Tags: python, packet, pyshark

Is there an efficient way to get the offset of some field in a packet captured with `pyshark`?
For example, I need to get the offset of the source IP within the whole packet or within some layer header in the packet. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue. Here is a sample code:

```
import pyshark

packets = pyshark.FileCapture(input_file=pcap_file_dir)
print(int(packets[0].ip.src.pos)) # Prints the offset of source IP
```